# Wie üblich ist 'Feber' in Österreich?

Tags: austrian, time

Ich bin gerade am Lokalisieren eines Programmes und wollte für den Monatsnamen `Januar` in der österreichischen Fassung `Jänner` verwenden.

Dabei fiel mir auf, dass es auch einen `Feber` für `Februar` gibt. Auch im [Wikipedia-Artikel zu Februar](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Februar) gilt: *In Teilen Österreichs, in der Pfalz und im Schwäbischen wird er auch Feber genannt.*

Jänner ist mir als Süddeutschem bekannt und gut verständlich, ich habe es auch schon bei Österreichern gehört. Feber war mir aber neu.

Das [Ngram zu Januar, Jänner, Februar, Feber](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Januar,%20J%C3%A4nner,%20Februar,%20Feber&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) zeigt, dass Feber kaum genutzt wird 
[image: Ngram zu Januar,Jänner,Februar,Feber]

Dass Feber genutzt wird, zeigt auch ein anderes [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Feber&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=).
[image: Ngram zu Feber]

Aber die Verwendung der Austriazismen in Büchern muss nicht unbedingt der der gesprochenen Sprache entsprechen.

Meine Frage:
Wie üblich ist die Verwendung von Feber, insbesondere im Vergleich zu Jänner?

Comment: Wenn ich rede verwende ich fast ausschließlich Jänner & Feber (bin aus Kärnten). Ich würde entweder beides übersetzen oder überhaupt nichts. Denke es macht wenig Unterschied wenn es geschrieben wird.

Comment: Off topic: Eigentlich müßten die Monatsnamen von selbst richtig kommen, zumindest in neueren Betreibssystemen und Bibliotheken, die alle internationalisiert sind. Man muß eigentlich nur seine Lokalität richtig angeben.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Der erste Monat eines Jahres heißt in Österreich Jänner. Und zu Jänner passt Feber besser als Februar. Tatsächlich kenne ich "Feber" aber nur aus der Aufzählung von Monatsnamen:

> Jänner, Feber, März, April, ...

Diese Aufzählungs-Variante mit Feber ist meiner Beobachtung nach in Österreich üblicher als diese:

> Jänner, Februar, März, April, ...

In Österreich kaum zu hören (wenn dann meist von Immigranten aus Deutschland):

> Januar, Februar, März, April, ...

In einer Datumsangabe wird aber trotzdem meist "Februar" verwendet, und dieser Monatsname wird auch in österreichische Kalender gedruckt.

> *12. Februar 1934*

Nach dem ebengenannten Tag ist in Wien übrigens auch ein Platz benannt, der "12. Februar Platz" beim Karl-Marx-Hof, denn am 12. Februar 1934 brach in Österreich ein Bürgerkrieg aus.

Dieser Platz heißt eben NICHT "12. Feber Platz" sondern

> "12. Februar Platz"

---

Wenn du ein Programm von deutschem Deutsch in österreichisches Deutsch übersetzen willt, dann verwende "Jänner" und "Februar". Alle anderen Monatsnamen sind dieselben wie im deutschen Deutsch.

Willst du noch mehr übersetzen? Ich kann dir helfen. Schick mir eine Liste. Wenn sie nicht zu lang ist, übersetze ich sie dir kostenlos. Meine E-Mail-Adresse steht auf meiner Profil-Seite. (Meine Muttersprache ist österreichisches Deutsch und ich bin selbstständiger Softwareentwickler)

Comment: Danke für die Antwort und das Angebot. Das erklärt, warum es Feber gibt und ich es trotzdem nie gehört habe. Danke für das Angebot, aber ich brauche nur die Datumsangaben.

Comment: Exzellente Antwort. Daß „Feber“ benutzt wird, zeigen die Emails, die ich von der Uni-Wien erhalte. Daß es selten ist, sieht man daran, daß ich es auch nach 5 Jahren (hauptsächlich) in Österreich für einen Tippfehler hielt. Der Vorschlag von Herrn Schölnast wird auch dadurch gestützt, daß der iOS-Kalender „Jänner“ und „Februar“ verwendet. Die Kombination scheint also üblich zu sein.

Comment: Diese Ausführung ist exzellent.
Ich möchte allerdings hinzufügen: Feber wird in der gesprochenen Sprache, zumindest in Tirol, recht häufig verwendet.

Answer (score 6):

Ich gehe gerade die Volltextsuche von [ANNO](http://anno.onb.ac.at) durch:

*Feber* beginnt um 1850 herum. Es kommt generell selten vor. Bis 1875 (so ist die OCR) kommt es vor allem in Blättern im Osten vor. Siebenbürgen, Kronstadt, Teplitz-Schönau, Znaim, Pest, Prag. In Wiener Zeitungen vor allem, wenn es um etwas aus dieser Gegend geht, wenn es der Reim erfordert oder es die Sprachmelodie verbessert. Hervorstechend sind drei humoristische Blätter, zwei Gerichts-Zeitungen und die jüdisch-religiöse *Die Neuzeit* (die auch oft von den Gemeinden aus dem Osten berichtet).

In der Volltextsuche des Parlaments ist die Hochzeit 1950–1990.

Heinz Pohl in einem [Kommentar zum Feber](http://diepresse.com/home/meinung/gastkommentar/1440570/Deutsch-fur-Inlaender_Nur-noch-Ruckzugsgefechte#kommentar3614799):

> der "Feber" ist eine junge Kanzleiform, die man in den alten Wörterbüchern noch gar nicht findet (z.B. bei Grimm und Adelung) und die - im Gegensatz zu Jänner - nie volkstümlich war (dies war eher die Endbetonung Február).

Ich (geb. 1968 in Wien) habe Feber immer als etwas fremd empfunden, habe zeitweise geglaubt, es komme aus Deutschland, und es vor allem in Kalendern gefunden.

Answer (score 2):

"Feber" war früher viel stärker gebräuchlich, und ist es bis heute im Amtsdeutsch. Wenn Du Dir zB einen [Wiener Parkschein](http://diepresse.com/images/uploads/7/0/c/1402636/Parkscheine_Wien_1368695918582501.jpg) ansiehst, findest Du dort "Feber" zum Ankreuzen.

Anders als Januar ist aber Februar mittlerweile üblich und weit verbreitet.

Answer (score 2):

Feber wird im auch umgangssprachlich ausschließlich im Burgenland verwendet. Man lernt es im Allgemeinen in der Volksschule, in den täglichen Gebrauch ist es aber nur im Burgenland übernommen worden.

Comment: Der erste Satz scheint zu viele Wörter zu haben.